# Button not clickable with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to click a button using selenium but it keeps saying that the element isn't interactable even though it is visible on screen and I can manually click it. I've tried webdriverwait, implicitly wait and many other solutions but none seem to work. Please can anyone offer a solution.
I've attached the buttons code and my own code.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
browser = webdriver.Chrome('')
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.get('https://www.aldi.co.uk/kirkton-house-high-back-desk-chair/p/709360437078000')
browser.maximize_window()
buybutton = False

while not buybutton:
    try:
        addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name('disabled')
        print("Button isn't ready yet.")
        time.sleep(1)
        browser.refresh()
    except:
        time.sleep(2)
        addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="addToBasketButton"]')
        addToCartBtn.click()
        
     
        buybutton = True
```

```html
<div class="product-details__selectButton" data-component="productAdder">
                <span class="js-sticky-atc__anchor"></span>
                <button class="product-details__cta js-product-cta button button--big button--rectangle button--transactional" type="submit" data-sku="709360437078000" data-limit="" data-limit-error="Sorry, you can only purchase 10 of this item." data-stock="inStock" data-stock-error="Out of stock" data-stock-pack-cta1="true" data-stock-pack-cta2="true" data-csrftoken="207d2b40-a785-40b6-89cd-987eba44a31c" data-is-buy-online="true" data-api="/api/cart/add" data-purchase-disabled="" aria-label="Add Kirkton House High Back Desk Chair to the basket" aria-controls="minicart-trigger" id="addToBasketButton">
                    <span class="js-product-cta-label" data-product-added="PRODUCT ADDED">
                        ADD TO BASKET</span>
                    <svg class="icon icon--basket">
                        <use xlink:href="/assets/8b290d70406f652780c7cc1c72fe4a88/dist/icons/sprite.symbol.svg#basket"></use>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//ul[contains(@class,'errors')]//following::form[contains(@class,'product-form')]//button[@id='addToBasketButton']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `xpath` you are using with **ID** `addToBasketButton` has two web elements :

Use this **CSS_SELECTOR** Instead :

```
ul.product-details__list.product-details__list--errors+form div.product-details__selectButton button
```